# How can i set the color for some part of the dygraphs?

Tags: php, ajax, javascript, dygraphs

i want to use the dygraphs for my site but in some part i need to show in my graph some part in background of my chart in color.
for example  in my chart i want that it show my in color green when we are in daylight.
could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some examples of highlighting particular time periods here:

http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/highlighted-weekends

http://dygraphs.com/tests/highlighted-region.html

Answer (score 0):

You could check the examples above and you can see that:
-on the dygraphs options set the underalayCallback with your own function
-with your function you can controll the canvas that is drawn because you have the canvas,the context and the dygraph object
-set the fillstyle with your desired color or better the gradient color
-based on the region that you want to fill set the fillRect on the canvas

hope this helps

Daniel